# Cygwin g++ and declaration does not declare anything

Tags: c++, cygwin

First of all, I'm not a keen user of C/C++ but I've got one project which was written in both languages. Furthermore, it's based on some Unix types (so VS is not an option, is it?) I'm currently using Windows 7 x32 and I decided to take a look at Cygwin (g++ compiler). But before moving the whole project I wanted to try it with less difficult situations.

So I have

main.cpp

```
#include <iostream>
#include "h/math.h"

int main()
{
    Math math; // just declare the Math variable, nothing else

    std::cin.get();
    return 0;
}
```

math.h

```
#ifndef math
#define math

class Math
{
public:
    int Addition(int, int);
    int Multiplication(int, int);
};

#endif
```

math.cpp

```
#include "math.h"

int Math::Addition(int x, int y)
{
    return x + y;
}

int Math::Multiplication(int x, int y)
{
    return x * y;
}
```

Then I open "...\Cygwin\Cygwin.bat", set the path to my files (cd C:\Proj) and try to compile with the following command:

$ g++ main.cpp

And what I've got is an error:
    *main.cpp: error: declaration does not declare anything*

What's wrong? As I understand it doesn't like my "Math math" line but trying that in my VS2010 there is no such an error. Is it happening due to g++ compiler? Doesn't it support "class" declaration? What should I change to run that code?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You `#define math` in your header. So the preprocessor sees `Math math` and goes "Oh, wait, `#define math`, so `Math` is the correct replacement". So when the declaration is given the compiler, it sees `Math ;`. This is obviously not kosher. Macros should always go in all caps, and header guards in particular usually take a form that's extremely specific, like, `HEADER_GUARD_MATH_H` or something like that.

Comment: imho, that pattern is too simple already, in case you are making use of sub-directories. Otherwise nice answer, +1.

Comment: Yeah, thanks pal. I changed the header and it compiled but I've got another problem here. Now when I try to do "cout << math.Addition(20, 40) << endl;" it shows the following error: "undefined reference to 'Math::Addition(int,int)'". What's wrong again?

Comment: @Semuserable: No idea. Ask another question.

Comment: @Semuserable: Either ask another question, or look into andrews_nz' answer.

Answer (score 1):

You may also get into problems when compiling math.cpp. Your compiler might get confused with

```
#include "math.h"
```

which may point to the `math.h` C header.

Also, it is really bad to `#define math`. You should never, ever `#define` a macro with such simple name. And the best example for why not is your code:

```
Math math;
```

but each occurence of `math` tokens is preprocessed into/replaced by the content of that macro:

```
Math ;
```

For header gurads, I typically recommend the pattern `FILENAME_EXT_INCLUDED_YYYYMMDD`, in your case

```
#ifndef MATH_H_INCLUDED_20120710
#define MATH_H_INCLUDED_20120710
...
#endif
```

simple patterns like `MATH_H` might be too simple already, as you may introduce other `math.h` in the future (this happened to me in the past more than once, ever since I use the pattern with the date).

Answer (score 0):

You have to include all the source files on the command line, e.g. `g++ main.cpp math.cpp`.

Comment: Thanks to you too! If I had more of a reputation I would have voted for your post.